# Download font file from server in java

Tags: java

I am new in java and would like to download some font file from serve through ftpclient..I have successfully downloaded some fonts of format `.ttf` while am facing problem in downloading `.woff` format files. Can anyone help me with this? I have included part of my code. No exception is shown but while calling `ftpclient.retrievefile()` i get `false` as reply. The path is correct and server have the file i am about to download

```
File downloadFile1 = new File(FileSavedPath);//creating new file
OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));
String path = "/dv2/" + fctypeId + "/" + remotefilename;
boolean success = false;
try 
{
    success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(path, outputStream);

}
catch(CopyStreamException cp)
{
    out.println(cp.getMessage());
}
catch(FTPConnectionClosedException error) 
{
    out.println(error.getMessage());
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
outputStream.close();
```

Now i see that some latin fonts gets downloaded but  while calling .retrievefil,it doesnot return TRUE.

Comment: The download should work. Maybe if the FTP server is old and uses DOS 8.3 file name format, you would need to shorten the extension as `.wof`; but you would see that. _Using_ the font is the problematic part I think.

Comment: you can try iterating over the files your ftpclient can reach, and also check for file permissions. what ftp client are you using? apache commons?

Comment: yes i am using apache commons.and there is not any problem with the server as same thing has been succesfully done using .net.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any obvious bugs in the code, and if it works for the `.ttf` files then I can only imagine it's some subtle typo in the path.

Can you try printing out the path that you are retrieving so you can double-check it?

```
...
try
{
    System.out.println("Retrieving: '" + path + "'");
    success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(path, outputStream);
}
...
```

Also, I wonder whether the `ftpClient` is in some kind of pending state due to previous actions? Can you isolate this retrieval so that nothing else but connection to the FTP site is performed before it?

Comment: I already have checked the path and its fine.And about that isolating the retrieval,i didnot get that.Can you be more elaborate....

Comment: You do not show how the ftpClient is constructed and connected, nor whether any other methods are called on ftpClient before the code you posted is run. I would suggest you write the shortest possible **complete** and **runnable** code that demonstrates the problem. It is not necessary to clutter up the code with lots of exception-handling; simply have your `public static void main(String...args)` method `throws Exception`. Your code does not appear to have any obvious bugs in it (from my close reading) so the problem is likely to be elsewhere.